# awk: concat string with number in dict value

Tags: awk

I have next awk oneliner :

```
{dict[$2"@"$6]=($(NF-2)/($(NF-2)+$NF))*100 } END {for (a in dict) {  printf "%s %d :" ,  a, int(dict[a]) }}
```

What i need, is to add to value of each dictionary key  combination of

```
($(NF-2)/($(NF-2)+$NF))*100 " out of"  $(NF-2)+$NF
```

So i want awk to calculate all math , then compose string and put it as dictionary value.  I already tried with some combination of spaces and brackets  but still no luck.

Vars are filled from input stream  :

```
$2 - host , not unique in input stream
$3 - partition , not unique in input stream
$NF - space avail 
$NF-2 - space used
$(NF-2)+$NF - gives you overall capacity of partiton
```

Output is

```
80% host1@/local/1
```

Output expected:

```
80% host1@/local/1   out of 112G
```

----------------------Solution-----------------------------------

With  good catch below , i resolved this. Issue was that i did int() in printf part, that truncated output. Though, further i faced other problems with my wrap-around shell part, therefore my  final code was different than i expected it to be asking question.

```
'{key=($2 "@" $6 " out of " int((($(NF-2)+$NF)/1000)/1000) "GB" ) ; dict[key]=($(NF-2)/($(NF-2)+$NF))*100 } END {for (a in dict) {  printf "%s ,  %d :" ,  a, int(dict[a]) }}'
```

I`ve moved "out of " and capacity part to dictionary key ,  because dict value cannot be string  in my case,  futher i will compare it with INT.

Comment: I`ve added details, but they have  low importance in scope of my question. Question is,  how to concat (as sting) result of math +  string + result of math,   to place it into the dictionary . I start to think that awk have problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation is working fine. It's not the problem.

The problem is that you are calculating the `int()` of the dictionary value when you print. Since the value is a string, the result is truncated. If you need to use `int()` do it at the time you perform the calculations rather than at print time.

By the way, if you had provided some sample data it would have been a lot easier to test your code and provide an answer. This is especially important since it's sometimes the case, as it is here, that the problem is in a place that is not where it was anticipated.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. I feel stupid now. Indeed , i completely forgot about printf part , and haven`t checked it.